# parse.com - query Constraints on filed just if exist

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

How can I do it?

```
    query.exists("year");
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("year", toYear);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("year", fromYear);
```

When the code is like above I get an error - I think it is because I have blank filed "year".
How can I do the Constraints on the "year" filed only if the "exists" is true?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

simply use two queries..

```
//1st query
query.exists("year");
query.find{
  success:{
    //2nd query
    query.lessThanOrEqualTo("year", toYear);
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("year", fromYear);  
    query.find{
      success:{
        //desired result
      }
    }

 }error:{
   //"year does not exists";
}
```